# How to overide keystore alias in sslContextParameter in camel

Tags: xml, apache-camel, keystore, jks, sslcontext

We are trying to use SSLContextParameter in camel 2.22.0 with Tomcat for https4 request.

Our goal is to use only one keystore for private/public key with multiple alias.
We load the spring ssContextParameter while camel is loading, and we want to use only alias when we define hhtps4 Endpoint, without defining a new sslContextParameter for each Endpoint in our route (~50 routes).

```
<camel:sslContextParameters id="sslAPPContextParameters"
        xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" >
        <camel:trustManagers>
            <camel:keyStore password="${truststore.jks.file.password}"
                resource="${truststore.jks.file.location}" />
        </camel:trustManagers>
        <camel:keyManagers>
            <camel:keyStore password="${keystore.jks.file.password}"
                resource="${keystore.jks.file.location}" />
        </camel:keyManagers>
    </camel:sslContextParameters>
</beans>
```

Is it possible ?
I found "sslContextParameters/@certAlias" but it seems to need a new sslContextParameter definition to use it, which is not my need due to our huge number of camelRoute.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ah okay, so you have many different certificates in the same keystore, and you want to specify which certificate more easily from each http endpoint? If so then maybe we can take a look and see if we can do something in Camel to support this.

Comment: That's it, I want to limit the number of keystore (with public/private key) and truststore (for public certificate) and would like to initialise only one time the sslcontextparameter and choose my keystore alias depending of the endpoint i need to request.I know it exists in webMethods and I would like to implement this in our camel project.
OR, if we can't use the same SSLContextParameter more than once, define a new SSLContextParameter - which reference the first - with an alias.
Thansks in advance.

Comment: Ah thanks, you are welcome to log a JIRA ticket at Apache Camel: http://camel.apache.org/support.html

Comment: Hi Claus, I just log a Jira Ticket (in French sorry) https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12719

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know:

1. There is one (and only one) cert alias per sslContextParameters instance
2. The HTTP4 component supports only one instance of SSLContextParameters per component (clearly explained in http://camel.apache.org/http4.html)

This means that your Camel routes are sharing the same SSL conf, and it would therefore not be a good idea to override the cert alias in multiple places (and with a different value).

I'm afraid the only solution is to define N variants of the HTTP component accompanied by its corresponding SSL conf:

```
<bean id="httpX" class="org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpComponent">
   <property name="sslContextParameters" ref="sslContextParams1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="httpY" class="org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpComponent">
   <property name="sslContextParameters" ref="sslContextParams2"/>
</bean>
```

and later use the appropriate one in your https endpoints